# Copy an IRL instead of a URL?

Tags: vimperator, pentadactyl

IRL is a UTF-8 encoded page address, in contrast URL which only allows a subset of ascii and everything beyond that is percentage-encoded.

In pentadactyl IRL appears,

- in an address bar:

  [image]

  and
- as a "Referer" in <kbd>g Ctrl-g</kbd>:

  [image]

(for example visit this page: [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сусанин,_Иван](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD))

However when one copies an address with <kbd>y</kbd> a URL is copied instead of a IRL. Firefox has an option `network.standard-url.escape-utf8` which lets users copy IRL instead of a URL in an address bar. But this [doesn't affect](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pentadactyl/FKcvZ6h2JvU/9o1NpM5hjgMJ) pentadactyl's <kbd>y</kbd> behaviour.

I think there might be a good reason to use URL instead of IRL, but I want to copy IRL.

One way to do it -- is to select the address in the address line, and copy it. But it is tedious.

Is there a way to copy an IRL instead of a URL with a shortcut key in pentadactyl?

**Edit**:

Here's a code of `yank-location` which is binded to `y`:

```js
mappings.add([modes.NORMAL],
    ["y", "<yank-location>"], "Yank current location to the clipboard",
    function () {
        let { doc, uri } = buffer;
        if (uri instanceof Ci.nsIURL)
            uri.query = uri.query.replace(/(?:^|&)utm_[^&]+/g, "")
                                 .replace(/^&/, "");

        let url = options.get("yankshort").getKey(uri) && buffer.shortURL || uri.spec;
        dactyl.clipboardWrite(url, true);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea. Is there any reason why it is not a defualt behavior, I wonder.

A rough guess:

```
:map y -js dactyl.clipboardWrite(util.losslessDecodeURI(buffer.uri.spec), true)
```

But note, that it would break yanking short URIs (e. g. on YouTube) and probably something else.

Or you might adapt a full code for `y` from `commons/modules/buffer.jsm`:

```
com yanklocation -description "Yank current location to the clipboard" 
    \ -js <<_EOF
    let { doc, uri } = buffer;
    if (uri instanceof Ci.nsIURL)
        uri.query = uri.query.replace(/(?:^|&)utm_[^&]+/g, "")
                            .replace(/^&/, "");

    let url = options.get("yankshort").getKey(uri) 
        && buffer.shortURL 
        || uri.spec;
    dactyl.clipboardWrite(util.losslessDecodeURI(url), true);
_EOF
map y -ex yanklocation
```

Comment: It works. I wonder why do you say it would break yanking short URLs? I guess it is not a default behaviour, because there's w3.org spec saying non-ascii URLs should be percentage encoded.

Comment: @Adobe Because it actually breaks it. :-)

Comment: I just visited youtube, and ow.ly and it seems to be yanking just fine.

Comment: See the edit of the question post: pentadactyl's `yank-location` does `options.get("yankshort").getKey(uri) && buffer.shortURL || uri.spec`.

Comment: This seems to be working: `:map y -js dactyl.clipboardWrite(util.losslessDecodeURI(options.get("yankshort").getKey(buffer.uri) && buffer.shortURL || buffer.uri.spec), true)`

Comment: @Adobe Why don’t use the whole function, actually. See edited answer.